# WSOD on File Upload

Tags: file-uploads

Seeing this message when tryig to upload an image.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\imagecreatefromstring() in
> /var/www/html/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php:192
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Mime_type.php(121):
> EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\MimeType->fileIsImage('/tmp/php3SUta2')
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Upload.php(553): Mime_type->fileIsImage('/tmp/php3SUta2') #2
>
> /var/www/html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Upload.php(209):
> EE_Upload->is_allowed_filetype() #3
> /var/www/html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(1890):
> EE_Upload->do_upload('file') #4
> /var/www/html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(1024):
> Filemanager->_upload_file(Array, 'file') #5
> /var/www/html/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/File/Upload.php(299):
> Filemanager->upload_file('7', 'file') #6
> /var/www/html/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Files/Files.php(138):
> EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\File\Upload->uploadTo('7') #7
> [interna in
> /var/www/html/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php
> on line 192

Uploads work fine on my development and staging areas, but not on production. So might be something to do with the server config?

Not sure, first time i've seen this error...

Other similar queires point to making sure fileinfo in exanbles, and it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Reason was PHP GD was not installed. Fixed by running the following on the server:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```