# PHP Fileinfo Issue Uploading Images

Tags: php-errors, ee4

After upgrading to EE 4 & PHP 7, when uploading a new image to the server in an entry, the upload fails and I get the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php:104 Stack trace:
#0 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/legacy/libraries/Mime_type.php(93): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\MimeType->ofFile('/tmp/phpsJV2ii')
#1 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/legacy/libraries/Upload.php(167): Mime_type->ofFile('/tmp/phpsJV2ii')
#2 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(1889): EE_Upload->do_upload('file')
#3 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/legacy/libraries/Filemanager.php(1023): Filemanager->_upload_file(Array, 'file')
#4 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/File/Upload.php(298): Filemanager->upload_file('1', 'file')
#5 /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Files/Files.php(137): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\File\Upload->uploadTo('1')
#6 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Control in /home/ihist/public_html/sketch/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on line 104
```

The last line leads me to believe it's an issue with the PHP fileinfo module, which I have enabled in my php.ini file with the following line:

```
extension = fileinfo.so
```

After that, I restarted Apache, but still no dice. This is eerily similar to [this post](https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/248935/file-upload-error) but I haven't had any luck. It's also pretty similar to [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/wsod-on-file-upload) but I can confirm GD is enabled!

It looks like file info is also installed by default with the following line:

```
'--enable-fileinfo=shared'
```

Some more details about my environment:

- EE 4.3.6
- PHP 7.0.33
- Apache 2.4.38 running linux

Notes:

- This error also occurs when syncing the file directory
- This error also occurs when uploading other file types besides .jpg,
  like .png

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something like this before. turned out that besides having to enable the fileinfo module, i had to activate it too

Answer (score 0):

While I had added it in the php.ini file, for some reason the fileinfo module was not loading. If you don't see the table in the PHP info page, the module isn't loading.

[image: Fileinfo Table from PHP]